# Excel macro add a cell value in a different worksheet based on a specific cell value in the first sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

[Click here  to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSSZ9.jpg)

Hi, I need someone to help me doing this scenario on my Excel 2007 :)

So here is the scenario :

- I input **QZ0821** in cell **B3** (sheet1)
- I click the **CommandButton1** activeX button. (sheet1)

After the ***commandButton1 is clicked***,

- Add text “**Ok**” automatically to cell **C3** right next  to the code (**QZ0821**) on sheet2 that I’ve input previously on sheet1 as well as if I fill out cell B3 (sheet1) with another code or value.

So whenever I input another code , for example QZ0822 (sheet1), then after I click the button, it will automatically add “Ok” next to cell that contains QZ0822 (sheet2).

Is it possible for me to do that?

Comment: Yes it is possible. There's already an answer that does the exact thing for you below, you only have to hook to the button click event now. Next time, please add some code and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehting like this?

```
Sub lookup()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet
    Dim wks2 As Worksheet

    Set wks1 = Sheets("Your Sheet 1") '<--- fill in your sheet name
    Set wks2 = Sheets("Your Sheet 2") '<--- fill in your sheet name

    strSearch = wks1.Range("B3").Value

    With wks2
        .Columns(2).Find(strSearch).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Ok"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could actually put this into the Worksheet_Change event. Then you don't need to press the button every time.